# Saving contents of a listBox to program settings C#

Tags: c#, listbox, properties.settings

So what I am trying to do is save the contents from a `listBox` to the application `Properties.Settings.Default`
I have no idea where to start, nor do I know if it is even possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

any settings you have setup in Properties-> settings tab should show up like

`[your namespace].Properties.Settings.Default.yoursetting = "change";`

after you edit your properties always call

`[your namespace].Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`

the save part got me at first.

for list types use :

[image: list setting]

it will help if your objects can be converted to and from strings anything more not really sure for anything more complex but I hope this gets you started.

`foreach(string s in listbox.Items){[settingscode].add(s);}`

something like that anyways.

Comment: How would I go about saving the contents of a listBox to Properties.Settings.Default....

Comment: [your namespace].Properties.Settings.Default.yoursetting.Add(); BTW

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to convert a listBox to a string. The method I am trying is not working.

Comment: what is your method? [settings code] = code from my comment. and if you could edit your question with a few lines of as to what you are trying would help